# Django queryset to list of ids with integer values

Tags: python, django

I need to retrieve IDs from multiple queries and add them into a list.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(category="Apple").values_list("product_id", flat=True)

reviewed = Reviews.objects.filter(category="Apple").values_list("product_id", flat=True)

selected_ids = [10,20,30]
```

Then I tried

```
all_products = selected_ids + products + reviewed
```

This raised error as list cannot be added to queryset.

so, I tried,

```
all_product_ids = selected_ids + list(products) + list(reviewed)
```

This works but, `all_products` has a mix of `int` and `tuple` values `[10, 20, 30, (2,), (2,), (1,)]`

I need them to be `[10, 20, 30, 2, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`union`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#union) and then add them with the list:

```
qset_ids = Product.objects.filter(category="Apple").values_list("product_id").union(Reviews.objects.filter(category="Apple").values_list("product_id"))

all_product_ids = selected_ids + list(qset_ids.values_list('product_id',flat=True))
```